# How to easily filter out a discriminated union case in FsCheck?

Tags: f#, fscheck

Consider a Discriminated Union:

```
type DU = | Foo of string | Bar of int | Baz of decimal * float | Qux of bool
```

I'd like to create a list of `DU` values with FsCheck, but I want none of the values to be of the `Qux` case.

This predicate already exists:

```
let isQux = function Qux _ -> true | _ -> false
```

**First attempt**

My first attempt to create a list of `DU` values without the `Qux` case was something like this:

```
type DoesNotWork =
    static member DU () = Arb.from<DU> |> Arb.filter (not << isQux)

[<Property(MaxTest = 10 , Arbitrary = [| typeof<DoesNotWork> |])>]
let repro (dus : DU list) =
    printfn "%-5b : %O" (dus |> List.exists isQux |> not) dus
```

Running this seems to produce a stack overflow, so I assume that what happens behind the scene is that `Arb.from<DU>` calls `DoesNotWork.DU`.

**Second attempt**

Then I tried this:

```
type DoesNotWorkEither =
    static member DU () =
        Arb.generate<DU>
        |> Gen.suchThat (not << isQux)
        |> Arb.fromGen

[<Property(MaxTest = 10 , Arbitrary = [| typeof<DoesNotWorkEither> |])>]
let repro (dus : DU list) =
    printfn "%-5b : %O" (dus |> List.exists isQux |> not) dus
```

Same problem as above.

**Verbose solution**

This is the best solution I've been able to come up with so far:

```
type WithoutQux =
    static member DU () =
        [
            Arb.generate<string> |> Gen.map Foo
            Arb.generate<int> |> Gen.map Bar
            Arb.generate<decimal * float> |> Gen.map Baz
        ]
        |> Gen.oneof
        |> Arb.fromGen

[<Property(MaxTest = 10 , Arbitrary = [| typeof<WithoutQux> |])>]
let repro (dus : DU list) =
    printfn "%-5b : %O" (dus |> List.exists isQux |> not) dus
```

This works, but has the following disadvantages:

- It seems like a lot of work
- It doesn't use the already available `isQux` function, so it seems to subtly violate DRY
- It doesn't really *filter*, but rather only produces the desired cases (so filters only by omission).
- It isn't particularly maintainable, because if I ever add a fifth case to `DU`, I would have to *remember* to also add a `Gen` for that case.

Is there a more elegant way to tell FsCheck to filter out `Qux` values?

Comment: +1 for the reminder about Baz and the introduction to Qux. Although it's a good question even without those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `Arb.generate`, which tries to use the registered instance for the type, which is the instance you're trying to define, which causes an infinite loop, use `Arb.Default.Derive()` which will go straight to the reflective based generator.

https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/master/src/FsCheck/Arbitrary.fs#L788-788

This is such a common mistake we should be able to solve out of the box in FsCheck: https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/issues/109

---

The particular problem in the OP can be solved like this:

```
type WithoutQux =
    static member DU () = Arb.Default.Derive () |> Arb.filter (not << isQux)

[<Property(MaxTest = 10 , Arbitrary = [| typeof<WithoutQux> |])>]
let repro (dus : DU list) =
    printfn "%-5b : %O" (dus |> List.exists isQux |> not) dus
```

Answer (score 6):

The below should work:

```
type DU = | Foo of string | Bar of int | Baz of decimal * float | Qux of bool
let isQux = function Qux _ -> true | _ -> false

let g = Arb.generate<DU> |> Gen.suchThat (not << isQux) |> Gen.listOf

type DoesWork =
    static member DU () = Arb.fromGen g

[<Property(MaxTest = 10 , Arbitrary = [| typeof<DoesWork> |])>]
let repro (dus : DU list) =
    printfn "%-5b : %O" (dus |> List.exists isQux |> not) dus
```

Note I used `Gen.listOf` at the end - seems like FsCheck fails to generate itself a list with the given generator

Comment: Well, that circumvents the issue by creating an `Arbitrary<DU list>` instead of an `Arbitrary<DU>`, which may solve my immediate problem, but doesn't seem to address the underlying problem.

Comment: Doesn't this pose the problem that we not don't get shrinking support for the DU?